# How to add headers on selected pages

Tags: fancyhdr

When I use `usepackage{fancyhdr}` and `pagestyle{fancy}` a header is added to every page of my project. How do I set headers on selected pages and how do I remove headers.

Comment: You can create a new page style using `\fancypagestyle`, although technically all fancy page styles work by modifying page style `fancy` temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

The command `\pagestyle` sets the default page style for subsequent pages, and it will use that style on every page that is not manually set to a different style, or until another such command is given.

You can override the style on a given page with `\thispagestyle`, e.g., `\thispagestyle{plain}` to get a simpler style (usually just a page number), or `\thispagestyle{empty}` to suppress all headers and footers. The command just needs to appear anywhere on that page before it is shipped.

Some document classes automatically set a different page style for the first page, so you may need to override it with `\thispagestyle`.

Of course it is also possible to specify different headers and footers for odd and even pages within a given style; the [fancyhdr documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en) gives the details, as well as how to create new styles and globally change an existing style like plain.

If those don't cover your use case, you'll need to explain more what you're trying to do.